# Exporting Java with VM arguments (or alternative)

Tags: eclipse, jar, jogl

I'm looking for a way to export a [JOGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_OpenGL) program that I wrote. Currently, I am referencing four JAR files with a user library, and I specify `-Djava.library.path=/lib` as a VM argument. The `/lib` folder contains some Mac OS X `.jnilib` files that JOGL needs to work.

Everything runs well in Eclipse, but I need a way to export this setup to an executable JAR file. When I export it though, it only exports the `JOGL.jars` and not the `.jnilibs`.

How can I reference the `.jnilibs` so that the exported JAR file can use them?

I spent four or five hours doing the tutorial *[Creating native binary executables for multi-platform Java applications with OpenGL and Eclipse RCP](http://wadeawalker.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/tutorial-creating-native-binary-executables-for-multi-platform-java-apps-with-opengl-and-eclipse-rcp/)* which worked, but it's unnecessarily bloated for something that is supposed to be a small application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think native libraries can be included in a JAR, they need to be available to the native OS to load and execute them. If they're in a JAR, the OS doesn't know what to do with that.

[Here](http://tlrobinson.net/blog/2009/03/09/embedding-and-loading-a-jni-library-from-a-jar/) is one hackish way that might work.

Also see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937406/how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar) for other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I use a program called [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice) to store native files inside the JAR.