# How to create JAR file with includes shared library(.so)

Tags: java, android, jar, java-native-interface

For one of my project I need to call native c code to my `java class`. For this I made following steps.

1. In my java class I declared some native methods which are required for my project. i.e

   ```
   public native String print(String pM,int len);

   public native int openPrint();
   ```
2. I initiated library file like below

   ```
   static
   {
       System.loadLibrary("print");
   }
   ```
3. After this I created header file with respect java code.
4. created c file and implemented above methods in c
5. after this I generated library file i.e `libprint.so` using `ndk-build`
6. library file is created successfully in `libs->armeabi->libprint.so`
7. whenever I run that java application it's giving error saying that

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
     no print in java.library.path
   ```

How do I solve this problem.?

I want to give this kind of application to other Android developers so that they can create this application without doing Native call and without creating `libprint.so` file

It means I have to give my own API to application developer. For this I have to create JAR file. which includes `java.class`, `libprint.so` (shared library)  and etc...

How to create JAR file which includes `libprint.so` also..

I am doing all above stuffs in ubuntu using eclipse and open-jdk6.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937406/how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar

Comment: Might want to take a look at a related Question. [how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937406/how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows if the jar use a dll, you must copy the dll to the root folder inside the jar. After that the program will find it.

Try it, it maybe help you.