# JNI Unsatisfied link error in distributed jar

Tags: java, java-native-interface, manifest, executable-jar

I have a java project that connects to a fingerprint scanner through a JNI library. I have the project running perfectly in netbeans with the jni files in the root directory of the java project. The problem occurs when I try and package it as a jar. Im having this error:

```
C:\Users\dwake\Desktop\OnceAgain\TestJob\dist>java -jar TestJob.jar
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no scannerJNI in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at scanner.scannerGUI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at scanner.main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:701)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:671)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

I know this is caused by a library file not being in the correct directory or not being found by the java virtual machine. How would I get my JNI libraries to compile with the jar?

P.S. I have tried opening the jar with 7zip and placing the .dll files in the jar but this hasnt helped.

Comment: Did it solve your issue?

Comment: No sorry :c I managed to get all of my source code deleted while trying to edit manifest files :/ Its okay though I have a backup. lol. Thanks anyway. I will keep trying

Comment: Check my answer if you need to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bundle a native library and a JNI library inside a JAR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937406/how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269570/how-to-package-opencv-java-in-a-jar/18780559#18780559

Comment: @alistair please see the dates. Then realize you are wrong. :) Enjoy your day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/dlls/ -jar TestJob.jar
```