# Create a jar file including an external library (OpenCV) in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I'm trying to create an executable jar of my application on a Mac, which uses functions from OpenCV. However when I try to create the jar in eclipse I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java248 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at imageRegistration.ImageGUI.main(ImageGUI.java:643)
```

The error I think is because the there is a .dylib file that is linked to the OpenCV jar and is not being packaged with it.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269570/how-to-package-opencv-java-in-a-jar), which seems to be the same issue I am having, but the solution doesn't work for me. This is what I have done:

```
public static void libLoad(){
    try{
    InputStream in = ImageGUI.class.getResourceAsStream("/lib/opencv-2.4.8 MAC/build/lib/libopencv_java248.dylib");
    File fileOut = File.createTempFile("lib", ".dylib");

    OutputStream out = FileUtils.openOutputStream(fileOut);
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    in.close();
    out.close();
    System.load(fileOut.toString());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to load opencv native library \n" + e);
    }
}
```

The error I get when I run this is:

```
Failed to load opencv native library 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

EDIT: Here is the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744)
    at imageRegistration.ImageGUI.libLoad(ImageGUI.java:624)
    at imageRegistration.ImageGUI.main(ImageGUI.java:643)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print full stack trace, it's not clear from where NPE is coming. Most probably ImageGUI.class.getResourceAsStream returns null. If this is true it is eihter because path is wrong or lib is not in the jar

Comment: At the moment I am adding the jar then adding the .dylib file to the native library path. Will the lib be in the jar?

Comment: try System.load(fileOut.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: That doesn't work, It seems to be happening when the file is being copying over

Comment: It is the native library linked to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put native OpenCV DLL file under the bin directory of JRE. At least it worked for me

Comment: I haven't tried on other machines. I don't see why not anw :)