# Running jar file returns java.library.path error

Tags: java, jar

I've built a jar through netbeans, specifying my main class and libraries. In the properties section, I have the library in the Libraries section and I've set

```
-Djava.library.path=/path/to/lib
```

in the Run section. However, when I run the jar file through the command line using

```
java -jar
```

it returns the error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libName in java.library.path
```

There is a lib directory in the same directory as my jar file, with the library in it, and the manifest file in the jar contains

```
Class-Path: lib/libName.jar
```

What's wrong with my jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.library.path` isn't used for loading `jar`-files but for loading *native* libraries used by e.g. JNI. From the error message it seems your application is calling `System.loadLibrary("libName")`, so your system is looking for `libName.dll` (on Windows) or `libName.so` (on Unix) which aren't there.

If you only have some classes in `libName.jar` you have no need for `System.loadLibrary()` nor for `java.library.path` - just include `libName.jar` in your classpath and java will find everything it needs.

If `libName.jar` contains native libraries you want to use: there's no straightforward way to load `dll`s or `so`s from inside a `jar` without unpacking them first, so the easiest way is to put the native library outside the jar as an extra file in your `/lib`-directory. There are also libraries out there that allow you to use the native lib from inside a jar - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937406/how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar) for more info.

Comment: If I have a .so file, where do I place it so I can build my project using netbeans? Do I need to use `System.loadLibrary("libName.so")` in my code?