# How to use library with jni in war file?

Tags: java, unix, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-native-interface

I have created a jar file using maven which uses a .so file with JNO. It has  .so ( dynamic library) in it. I used this jar file with a simple java program by putting it in the classpath and it worked.

Now I want to use it in war file as library. So, I have mentioned it as a dependency in pom file. But it gives error:

```
remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no example in java.library.path.
Please see server.log for more details.
Command deploy failed.
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937406/how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar