# Java - Run a jar with VM arguments without commandline

Tags: java, batch-file, jvm, lwjgl

I currently have a jar that needs the `-Djava.library.path` to be set for LWJGL on launch or it will throw an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. To negate this problem, I have launched the jar through CMD with that VM argument using a batch file (Windows).

My question is - is there any way to do this natively in the jar without requiring some kind of launcher?

Comment: Probable duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937406/how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the properties inside your program. Use either

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", "path/to/natives");
```

or

```
Configuration.LIBRARY_PATH.set("path/to/natives");
```

at the start of your main method.