# running a jar file on a server, but how to link its .so file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, .so

This might be a stupid question but I'm new to this. I have a jar file of an eclipse project. I need to run this on a server. I have transferred the file using filezilla and can ssh and run it, but I need to link it to its .so file. How do I do this?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried thusfar?

Comment: 'I need to link it to its .so file` - what do you mean ? Do you call something through JNI  ?

Comment: @Karan Maheshwari If you want to start an .so file you can do that per Runtime.getRuntime().exec("COMMAND"); It is like using the system console.

Comment: Try to copy the .so file to the same folder that placed your jar file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bundle a native library and a JNI library inside a JAR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937406/how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar)