# Running Google Dataflow job on startup

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Our Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline program calls some library which dynamically links to *.so files, so to run it I need to set linux environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. There is a hack to do that: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.java.programmer/LOu18-OWAVM, but I wonder is there a way to do that using some job that will run shell script before executing pipeline?

Comment: This needs to happen before the program runs at all? That is we can't just set the env vars in the Dataflow java program?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JNI for this? Can you set the environment variable in the Java code before your setup your JNI code?

You may also want to just load the .so file from the classpath and pass it in a stream. Is it possible to link in the .so file that way?

See filesToStage here for how to lookup the file.
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/specifying-exec-params

Perhaps the suggestions in these links could work as well, and you could package the .so file in your jar:
[How to bundle a native library and a JNI library inside a JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937406/how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar)

https://www.adamheinrich.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-load-native-jni-library-from-jar/