# Which Java API to use with JavaCV? org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core or org.opencv.core?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I'm playing with OpenCV in Java (actually in Scala).
I'm using org.bytedeco wrappers (opencpp and javacv), but the documentation is not great.

The question is that depending on the examples, two different APIs are used: **org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core** or **org.opencv.core**

**org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core** is working fine, but **org.opencv.core** throws java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: no opencv_java410 in java.library.path 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java410 in java.library.path
```

I'm completely lost:

1. Why two different apis?
2. Which one is the one to use?
3. Why **org.opencv.core** throws exception when **org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core** is working?

Thanks in advance.

Library used: "org.bytedeco" % "javacv-platform" % "1.5.1" that import lib for all platforms.

Comment: We would need to patch the loader from the `org.opencv` package to use JavaCPP's loader. That's not currently being done, so we need to do it manually as indicated in the README.md file here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv#documentation  Contributions to enhance this are welcome though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm completely lost:

The `org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core` and `org.opencv.core` libraries are Java *bridge* libraries that allow the OpenCV native library to be called.
The Java libraries are generated from the C/C++ header files for the OpenCV library.  For example, the [bytedeco.org](http://bytedeco.org/) site that their version using the [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) tool.

> 1. Why two different apis?

Because two groups decided to do this!  Clearly, it isn't a lot of work to generate the Java code.

Why did two groups decide to do the same thing?   Pass.

> Which one is the one to use?

Questions asking for recommendations are off-topic for StackOverflow, so I won't give one.

A pragmatic answer is to use the one that works for you, but you could also try and figure out what the other one doesn't work.

You should maybe consider the version of the OpenCV API that you want to use, and whether the bridge libraries for that version is available from the respective suppliers.

> Why `org.opencv.core` throws exception when `org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core` is working?

Both versions of the library need to link to the OpenCV native library.  This is linking is not working for `org.opencv.core` on your execution platform.  There are a couple of possible reasons for this:

1. One of the `opencv` libraries has an embedded copy of the library and the other doesn't.  (Look what is inside the respective JAR files, and compare them to what this Q&A says about how to embed native libraries: [How to bundle a native library and a JNI library inside a JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937406/how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar.))
2. Alternatively, neither of the JAR files embeds the native library, but your execution has an *appropriate* version of the library installed already.   The version that fails is looking for a library with the name "opencv_java410".

Comment: Thanks for your response. So basically, two different approaches, one is loading the embedded binary libraries automatically and the other one delegate this to the user so needs to have OpenCV installed in your environment.

Comment: Yes ... though I don't know this the actual issue here.