# Can one use binary packages both in Windows and Linux?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, operating-system, binaryfiles, java-11

I'm trying to install JDK & Java IDE, I have dual boot (Windows 10 + Ubuntu 18.04), can I make use of the same binary packages in both of my systems?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the "binary package" consists of.

- If it consists of just .class files and other machine independent resources, then yes the same binary can be used on multiple operating systems and even different hardware architectures.
- If it also includes native libraries, and the like, then those libraries will be operating system **and** hardware architecture specific.

  If your application "package" is a self-contained JAR file, then it is possible to include native libraries compiled for multiple platforms in the JAR; see [How to bundle a native library and a JNI library inside a JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937406/how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar)
- If the package is actually installable package as understood by the host system's package manager (e.g. a Linux RPM, DEB) or a native installer executable, then these are also platform specific.

---

It also depends on how you handle platform specific things in the application; e.g. running different external commands on different platforms, talking to the Windows Registry, LDAP vs Active Directory, different file system properties and behaviors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't easily have a single package. I don't know about NetBeans but Eclipse and Java are specific to the operating system because they use many APIs which are different in each OS.

Comment: Take a look at this:      https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb113/nb113.html     . . . same binary file for both Operating System. It's Apache Netbeans official webpage

Comment: So NetBeans is OK, Eclipse and Java itself definitely are not OK.

Comment: @greg-449 I don't see "same binary file for both Operating System" in the Netbeans package. Instead I see three "binaries": one `sh` shell script and two Windows binaries (32/64bit). Hence it is just a multi-platform archive.