# Add DLL/SO to Gradle Project (Micronaut APP)

Tags: gradle, micronaut, jib

Hello i am using a DLL over JNI within my micronaut app. Within a Gradle project and i have literally no idea, how to put the dll into the created container (we use jib)
Would be very appreciated, if someone has some hints how to approac that.
Unfortunately i have no glue and therefore no example to provide.

Regards
Oli

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile and/or the `build.gradle` to give more insight what you tried so far?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking to Jib's `extraDirectories` feature to copy arbitrary files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937406/how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar may help.