# JAR file compiled on IntelliJ not working in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, import, executable-jar

My Java application imports the **Xerial SQLite JDBC library v3.43.0.0** to perform some CRUD functions, and it works as expected. However, I want to export this class as a JAR file and use it in my Android mobile app. The basic functionalities of the JAR file appear to work as expected after being imported into the Android app. However, SQLite functions fail with this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libsqlitejdbc.so" not found
```

SQLite CRUD functions work correctly in the Android app as well, but not when invoked by the class functions within the JAR.

Any help would be much appreciated. TIA.

---

**@romanv-jb**

This is an IntelliJ build in Java:

[image]

The module settings:

[image]

The artifacts settings:

[image]

And the project structure:

[image]

---

**QUESTION:** Is it even possible for a JAR module to read/write to Android files or SQLite databases?

Comment: Which Build System your Project uses (Maven, Gradle, etc)?
How the dependency is declared? How are you building the JAR?

Comment: @romanv-jb, I've added the requested info into the original post. I hope it's helpful towards analyzing the problem.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6511351/104891. Native library has to be extracted and loaded from the file system. It cannot work from the jar file directly.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you have either add the library's source code or add it as a [Maven Dependency](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#download-libraries-from-maven).