# Loading OpenCV with System.load("path/to/opencv") fails on Windows, works on Linux

Tags: java, opencv, jar, java-native-interface, executable-jar

I am shipping an application that uses OpenCV as a single executable jar. To avoid the end user needing to download OpenCV on their own system, the OpenCV binaries are stored inside the jar, and extracted to a temp file, and loaded using `System.load()` with the tempfile path, per [this stackoverflow post suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937406/how-to-bundle-a-native-library-and-a-jni-library-inside-a-jar), as follows:

```java
public class NativeLibraryLoader {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    /**
     * This is a safe way to load a native library from a jar, assuming that library
     * is inside your resource director/classpath.
     */
    public static void loadLibraryFromJar(String libraryName) throws IOException {
        logger.debug("Loading native library %s".formatted(libraryName));
        InputStream is = NativeLibraryLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + libraryName);
        File library = File.createTempFile("jni-temp-file", "tmp");
        library.deleteOnExit();
        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(library)) {
            logger.debug("Copying library input stream to temp file " + library.getPath());
            os.write(is.readAllBytes());
        }
        logger.debug("Loading library " + library.getPath());
        System.load(library.getPath().replace("\\", "/"));
    }

}
```

This method works just fine on linux, when I am loading `opencv_490.so`. The library loads, and I am able to use OpenCV. However when running the same command on Windows using `opencv_490.dll`, it cannot find the library and I get an UnsatisfiedLink. The `loadLibraryFromJar` method throws the error at the call to `System.load()`, and produces the following error during the unit test:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.188 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.toughdata.autogrowth.TestOpenCVCaptchaProcessor
[ERROR] testSolveRotateCaptchaIsKnownValue  Time elapsed: 0.187 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\greg\AppData\Local\Temp\jni-temp-file78576686543799615tmp: Can't find dependent libraries
        at com.toughdata.autogrowth.TestOpenCVCaptchaProcessor.testSolveRotateCaptchaIsKnownValue(TestOpenCVCaptchaProcessor.java:16)

[ERROR] testSolvePuzzleCaptchaIsKnownValue  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.toughdata.autogrowth.automation.captcha.OpenCVCaptchaProcessor
        at com.toughdata.autogrowth.TestOpenCVCaptchaProcessor.testSolvePuzzleCaptchaIsKnownValue(TestOpenCVCaptchaProcessor.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\greg\AppData\Local\Temp\jni-temp-file78576686543799615tmp: Can't find dependent libraries [in thread "main"]
        at com.toughdata.autogrowth.TestOpenCVCaptchaProcessor.testSolveRotateCaptchaIsKnownValue(TestOpenCVCaptchaProcessor.java:16)

[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   TestOpenCVCaptchaProcessor.testSolvePuzzleCaptchaIsKnownValue:24 NoClassDefFound
[ERROR]   TestOpenCVCaptchaProcessor.testSolveRotateCaptchaIsKnownValue:16 » UnsatisfiedLink
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 19, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 8
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.035 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-03-11T09:04:46+11:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can see that the tempfile is created, and that the library is extracted and written to the tempfile. Does anyone know what could cause the call to `System.load()` to fail on windows when it works fine on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I was able to figure this out. I went out on a limb and changed the `tmp` extension to `.dll` when creating the temp file. It turns out that Windows expects the libraries to end with the `.dll` file extension. Linux does not care whether your libraries end with `.so` or not, but on windows they must end with `.dll`

The correct code for using System.load() to laod a dll from a jar on windows is as follows:

```java
public class NativeLibraryLoader {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    /**
     * This is a safe way to load a native library from a jar, assuming that library
     * is inside your resource director/classpath.
     */
    public static void loadLibraryFromJar(String libraryName) throws IOException {
        logger.debug("Loading native library %s".formatted(libraryName));
        InputStream is = NativeLibraryLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + libraryName);
        File library = File.createTempFile("jni-temp-file", ".dll");
        library.deleteOnExit();
        try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(library)) {
            logger.debug("Copying library input stream to temp file " + library.getPath());
            os.write(is.readAllBytes());
        }
        logger.debug("Loading library " + library.getPath());
        System.load(library.getPath().replace("\\", "/"));
    }

}
```