# "no sigar-x86-winnt.dll in java.library.path" error when using Hyperic SIGAR on multi language OS

Tags: multilingual, sigar

I am using [a Hyperic SIGAR](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar) library as third party lib in my installation program. 
My installation program unpacks all third lib files to the %TEMP%\\user folder.

On English OS's everything works great, but when i tried to run my setup program on Spanish Os, 
I've encountered the following error:

the java library includes the sigar.jar:

java.class.path=C:\DOCUME~1\**Spanish Letters**\CONFIG~1\Temp\e4j58.tmp_dir\user\sigar.jar

My installation program supports WinXP, WIN7 OS's.

The Error is:

```
no sigar-x86-winnt.dll in java.library.path
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: no sigar-x86-winnt.dll in java.library.path
at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.loadLibrary(Sigar.java:172)
at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.<clinit>(Sigar.java:100)
at I4jScript_Internal_1.eval(I4jScript_Internal_1.java:23)
at I4jScript_Internal_1.evaluate(I4jScript_Internal_1.java:79)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.Script.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runScript(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.runScript(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.control.RunScriptAction.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.SystemInstallOrUninstallAction.install(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl.performActionInt(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.ContextImpl.performAction(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.executeActions(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.handleCommand(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.handleStartup(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)'
```

Is someone already encountered a similar error and can advise?
Thanks.

Comment: try this example to load the file


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691095/java-loading-dlls-by-a-relative-path-and-hide-them-inside-a-jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sigar-x86-winnt.dll put in the current user directory, it will work

Comment: Could you please tell where can I get sigar-x86-winnt.dll ?

Comment: @StephenC...yes I got it somehow

Answer (score 2):

you should set System property (`java.library.path`)

ex) `java ... -Djava.library.path=../lib/sigar/lib ...`

`java.library.path` is folder that contain the `sigar-x86-winnt.dll`

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1299532

Answer (score 2):

You could also add to java.path.library at runtime programmatically.

```
    System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("java.library.path")+File.pathSeparator+pathToYourDLL);

    //set sys_paths to null
    final Field sysPathsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
    sysPathsField.setAccessible(true);
    sysPathsField.set(null, null);
```

A very good explanation is found at : http://fahdshariff.blogspot.jp/2011/08/changing-java-library-path-at-runtime.html

Answer (score 1):

as discussed in the docs, SIGAR uses JNI underneath. You have to include appropriate JNI file in the path (file is usually displayed in the stack trace).
If you are using maven to build the project, you should edit pom.xml to add this file to the path(alas, you cant specify artifact and assume it is going to be in path)

```
 <!-- add sigar dll to java path -->
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                    <workingDirectory>target</workingDirectory>
                    <argLine>-Djava.library.path=${basedir}/lib</argLine>
                </configuration>
```