# Hyperic Sigar Mac Osx Error -No Library

Tags: java, hyperic, sigar

Hi im using a third party lib name Hyperic Sigar. When i run my code it shows error,

This is my code:

```
package pack;

import org.hyperic.sigar.*;

public class NetworkData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
   Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
    }

}
```

This is the error message:

```
1 [main] DEBUG Sigar  - no libsigar-universal64-macosx.dylib in java.library.path
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: no libsigar-universal64-macosx.dylib in java.library.path
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.loadLibrary(Sigar.java:172)
    at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.<clinit>(Sigar.java:100)
    at pack.NetworkData.main(NetworkData.java:10)
```

Im developing on Mac Osx Snow Leopard Using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
is found some old post(["no sigar-x86-winnt.dll in java.library.path" error when using Hyperic SIGAR on multi language OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832751/no-sigar-x86-winnt-dll-in-java-library-path-error-when-using-hyperic-sigar-on))
The post says that i need to add some path, if so... How do i add that path in Mac Osx?
Do hope someone can help^^

Answer (score 5):

```
 # to find it later because you will need it ...
 cd ~/Downloads/

 # or whatever the latest one at the time of reading is ... 
 curl https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/sigar/sigar/1.6/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip

 # unpack the package to the tmp dir
 sudo unzip -o /Users/phz/Downloads/hyperic-sigar-1.6.4.zip -d /tmp/

 # copy the libsigar-universal64-macosx.dylib to your class path dir
 sudo find /tmp/ -name libsigar-universal64-macosx.dylib \
   -exec cp -v {} /Library/Java/Extensions/ \;

 # this cmd might be obsolete ... 
 # copy the sigar.jar to your class path dir
 sudo find /tmp/ -name sigar*.jar \
   -exec cp -v {} /Library/Java/Extensions/ \;

 # set you classpath dir, or add in ~/.bash_profile
 # or even better https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/ysg-confs
 export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Library/Java/Extensions

 # you should not see the error anymore 
 cd $my_proj_dir ; sbt compile

 # neither here .. 
 cd $my_project_dir ; clear ; sbt "test:testOnly *testClass"
```

Comment: For me, it was enough to download _sigar.zip_ from https://sourceforge.net/projects/sigar/ and extract `libsigar-universal64-macosx.dylib` to `/Library/Java/Extensions/`. This removed the warning from IntelliJ scala test run.

Answer (score 3):

First You need to add `Sigar.jar` to your library, then add .dylib file to your library (you need to pick file for your OS what you are using). In your case you should add `libsigar-universal64-macosx.dylib` you can find these files in `"hyperic-sigar-1.6.4/sigar-bin/lib"`.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution,
The solution is adding a jar file(in my case) to my project.
Is the same concept whenever we use a third party library,like mysql driver for java.
So in my case,
i need to add log4j.jar and sigar.jar to my path.

Right click on your eclipse project then go to 
Build Path > Configure Build Path > Java Build Path > Add External JARs 
and add in sigar.jar to your project.