# Maven - UnsatisfiedLinkError with java.library.path

Tags: maven, java-native-interface

I'm having a problem with trying to get Maven to load my native library. Currently, I placed my library file (.so) in `src/main/resources/` and it gives me an error of it cannot be found in java.library.path. I also tried to place this in my base directory of the project, but gives me the same results.

Below is the maven plugin I tried, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <systemProperties>
        <property>
          <name>java.library.path</name>
          <value>${project.build.directory}</value>
        </property>
      </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

If it helps, I run my project directly from Eclipse. I know how to get it to work in Eclipse but want it to work with maven.

@EDIT I also tried running it on the command line and I still receive the same mistakes

Comment: I understand that the `${project.build.directory}` point to `${basedir}/target`. You've mentioned that the `.so` is placed at `src/main/resources` which will be copied to `${project.build.directory}/classes` (`${basedir}/target/classes`).

Comment: But when I look in the jar it's at the base

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The produced jar file contains that resource at the base level. But the surefire executes before that. The phase test comes before phase package. Please refer to http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: Is there any way to point to the one in the jar? or a folder in the jar, say lib/?

Comment: I only used to point to the full path to dll/so and understand that it is not possible to point to the jar file. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691095/java-loading-dlls-by-a-relative-path-and-hide-them-inside-a-jar/4691879#4691879

Answer (score 3):

I did the following in my project:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <argLine>-Djava.library.path=/path/to/your/libs:${java.library.path}</argLine>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And it worked for me that way.