# java.library.path : sigar-amd64-winnt.dll is setted but not found

Tags: java, maven, dll, applet

1st, sorry for my english, I'm french but I think it's just the best website for my question !

I'm trying to put two dll in my jar : sigar-amd64-winnt.dll and sigar-x86-winnt.dll

It's a Maven project and the objective is to make an applet for a bigger project, so I can't put it in a system or user folder.

DLLs are in the jar's root, so I can extract and load them with this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4691879/4261971
(They are extracted in the java temp folder).
I use the `System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("java.library.path") + MyLibDirectory)` function to reference the dll in the java.library.path, and it's work ! I can see it if I use `System.getProperty("java.library.path")`.

But the error is always the same :

`no sigar-x86-winnt.dll in java.library.path
at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.loadLibrary(Sigar.java:172) etc...`

Function (simplified) which call the sigar library :

```
public String getfileVersion(String fileDir) {
    String version = "";
    if ((!fileDir.isEmpty()) && (!"".equals(fileDir))) {
        FileVersion info = Win32.getFileVersion(fileDir);
        version = info.getFileVersion();
    }
    return version;
}
```

The finality of the applet is to inspect a user computer directly from the global web application and generate a log.

The part of Maven pom.xml for including dlls :

```
<build>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>libs</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>sigar-amd64-winnt.dll</include>
      <include>sigar-x86-winnt.dll</include>          
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

I worked three working days on this problem and I don't understand my mistake at this time, so if you can help me, I will love you for the rest of my life ! (lol)

If you want more informations, just ask !

Answer (score -1):

System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("java.library.path") + System.getProperty("path.separator")+ MyLibDirectory);
or
 System.setProperty("org.hyperic.sigar.path",MyLibDirectory);

Comment: Please, make your answer more detailed not just the code.

Comment: Please consider formatting the code and explain in more detail